# Safari shows a "This connection is not private" warning using Charles Proxy with SSL Proxying enabled

Tags: ssl, safari, charles-proxy

I'm running Charles Proxy (version 4.6.2) with SSL proxying enabled for *.apple.com:

[image]

I've trusted the Charles root certificate in Keychain Access on my MacBook Pro running macOS Monterey:

[image]

yet when I navigate to apple.com in Safari, I get a "This Connection Is Not Private" warning:

[image]

In Chrome, however, I'm able to browse to Apple.com normally:

[image]

Does Safari not use Keychain Access as its trust store? Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: it could be certificate pinning

Comment: Does it happen for other websites?

Comment: Regarding whether it could be certificate pinning, according to https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29990/158465 that feature was never implemented for Safari?